# How to get real size of image and resized in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular

There is an image:

```
@ViewChild('image')
readonly image: ElementRef;
```

Html:

```
 <img #image class="image" />
```

How to get real size (width, height) and resized size after autofit by CSS?

I have tried this:

```
  console.log(this.container.nativeElement.clientHeight);
  console.log(this.container.nativeElement.clientWidth);
```

It returns me 500 and 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this :

```
<img #image src="images/path" class="image" (load)="onLoad()" />
```

**in controller**

```
onLoad() {
  console.log((this.image.nativeElement as HTMLImageElement).width);
  console.log((this.image.nativeElement as HTMLImageElement).height);
}
```

demo : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rqceml?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this:

```js
  console.log((this.container.nativeElement as HTMLImageElement).naturalWidth);
  console.log((this.container.nativeElement as HTMLImageElement).naturalHeight);
```

Comment: Property 'naturalWidth' does not exist on type 'HTMLElement'

Comment: I forgot to cast the object to HTMLImageElement, but I changed the answer